# How to send multiple query using dbFetch in R foreach loop?

Tags: sql, r, database, foreach

I am using R foreach package to speed up my loop of downloading data from the server via SQL and dbFetch syntax as follows:

```
#library packages
library(RPostgres)
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#Setup backend to use many processors
totalCores = detectCores()
#Leave one core to avoid overload your computer
cluster <- makeCluster(totalCores[1]-1) 
registerDoParallel(cluster)

# connect the server
wrds <- dbConnect(Postgres(),host='wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu',
              port=9737,user=userid,password=pw,dbname='wrds',sslmode='require')

# Download Data from server
foreach (j = 1:length(Datetemp), .packages = "RPostgres") %dopar% {
      date <- as.character(Datetemp[j])
      query <- paste0("select * from ", "taqmsec.ctm_", date, 
                     " where sym_root = '", sym, "' and ", 
                     "time_m between '09:30:00.000' and '16:00:00.000'")
      res <- dbSendQuery(wrds, query)
      data <- dbFetch(res, n = -1)
      dbClearResult(res) 
      write.csv(data, row.names = FALSE, file = paste0(sympath, "/", sym, "_", date, ".csv"))
      print(paste0("Finished Stock ", sym, " for Date ", date))
}
```

The codes return errors of:

```
    > task 1 failed - "external pointer is not valid"
```

Can someone tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot pass pointer-based objects such as the database connection to child processes. This means that each node in your `cluster` needs to instantiate its own `wrds` connection object.

Comment: FYI, you aren't doing anything fancy enough with your queries to necessitate using the triple-call of `dbSendQuery`, `dbFetch`, and `dbClearResult`. Get it all done with `data <- dbGetQuery(wrds, query)` and reduce to a single expression.

Comment: Lastly, you should consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Comment: (Though parameterized queries won't work for determining the table to use, so you'll still be stuck `paste`ing _that_ portion into the query, but you really should stop pasting `sym` into it.)

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your suggestions. I also tried putting the wrds connection, which is pointer-based objects, to each child process. It worked BUT the server returns "too many connections", which is inevitable. Does it mean impossible to apply parallel execution of dbFetch here? (I also tried sapply, which does not have problem of pointer-based objects, but the speed is still not good)

Comment: Do you know what your limit is?  The "too many connections" is completely policy-based, if you cannot change the policy (talk to your DBAs) then no parallel code is going to be able to circumvent it.